# I'm stuck in rendering templates using express and handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, rendering

Please, explain me, why my code does not work?
I'm using express width handlebars, for form submit using Jquery Ajax. First render works properly, but second does not. I think that the problem is in nesting 'res.render'. Hope on your answers :-)

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var template = require('consolidate');
var handlebars = require('handlebars');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.engine('hbs', template.handlebars);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', __dirname);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    myName: 'John'
  });
});
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  var obj = {surname: req.body.surname, age: req.body.age};
  res.render('Layout.hbs', obj, function(err, html) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(html);
      res.render('index.hbs', {
        content: html
      })
    }
  }
  );
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('App listening on 8080');
});
```

index.hbs

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <p>{{myName}}</p>
    </div>
    <form action="" name="form" id="form" method="post">
      <input id="surname" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="surname"><br/>
      <input id="age" type="text" name="age" placeholder="age"><br/>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
    {{{content}}}
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var surname = form.find('#surname').val();
        var age = form.find('#age').val();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          data: {surname: surname, age: age},
          success: function(res) {
            console.log('Success');
          },
          error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Layout.hbs

```
<div class="inner-container">
  <h1>{{surname}}</h1>
  <h2>{{age}}</h2>
  <p>Render</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you nesting `res.render()` calls?  One render on the content should be enough.

Comment: I need to render "Layout" template inside "index", how can i perform this without nested render?

Comment: Handlebars has its own mechanism for embedding another template inside of the main one.  You need to use that mechanism, not call `res.render()` twice. If you show the actual templates and explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish, we'd be more likely to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right, the problem is with nested `res.render`. When you call `res.render`, it renders a html and sends it to the client with a status code of `200`.

You can call `app.render` on root level and `res.render` only inside a route/middleware. But keep in mind, `res.render` uses `app.render` internally to render template files. I don't think there is any need of rendering template separately.

Hope the answer helps you. It would be better for me to answer if I could see the error log that you are getting. If you provide that I would change my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue with binding delegation event with on() method..

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
```

Replace it by

```
$(document).on('submit','form', function(e)){
```